# If all the inputs aren't selected/focused

Tags: jquery

Is there a way that you can check if there isn't a input selected (text input)

I tried

```
if(!$('input').is(":selected")) {
       alert('hoi');
};
```

but it doesn't work

I dont want to use `focus out` because if i'm going from textfield 1 to textfield 2 the alert comes, so I'm looking for a code that do: if all the inputs arn't focussed then the alert comes on the screen

Comment: how can more than one elements of type input will have focus on it??

Comment: that i dont want? i want that there comes a message when there is none of the textfields focussed. if im working with `focusout` and im going from textfield 1 to textfield 2 then he deselect first textfield 1 and then focus text field 2 only is it possible to use like this


'if(!$("#t1").focus() && $("#t2").focus() && $("#t3").focus(){ alert("hoi");}'

Comment: Just set a variable to true on focusout and false on focus and check this variable

Comment: what about .focusin() ?

Comment: @VilasKumkar I tried but when i'm focussing a textbox and then cancel the focus there comes no message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

:selected only works for option elements.

See: http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

You want to use the :focus selector.  A generally accepted way to test if elements exist on a page (in this case focused elements) is to use the .length attribute.

```
if(!$('input:focus').length) {
    alert("None selected")
}
```

Comment: it only works when no-one have selected any inputs but when someone focus an input and unfocus it,  it doesn't works.

Comment: Where are you running this code?  You might want to check what element is being focused, does this fiddle help?

http://jsfiddle.net/0rkpbLyn/